# VueJs / Ionic - DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, dom

I have a list of objects, which I display through a v-for directive. Every time I am trying to add another object to the list I get the following error :

[Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21PmW.png).

Vue component :

```
<ion-col v-for="specificOffer in specificOffers" :key="specificOffer.specificOfferId">
```

where:

```
computed: {
 ...mapGetters("specificOffer", {specificOffers: "getSpecificOffers"})
}
```

JS for updating specificOffers list :

```
updateSpecificOffers(state, payload){
    state.specificOffers.push(payload);
},
```

After pushing the new object to the list I get that error. I don't have duplicates in the list and I also don't use any v-if directive
[screen from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynGmK.png).

If needed, here is the flow:
[getting specificOffers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDorH.png), [adding the object to the db and then to the state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlEPL.png).

I have no idea how to fix this bug. I would appreciate any help.

Regards,
Cezar